# How to sync an additional folder to iCloud Drive similar to how macOS Sierra does it?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization

I want to add my Downloads folder to my iCloud Drive so that it can sync just like Sierra syncs with the Documents and Desktop folder.

Can this be done?

Comment: Look into symbolic links.

Answer (score 23):

Similar answer to one of the others, but in this case I've used a symbolic link to do this rather than use the GUI to create an apple 'Alias', just to be sure it works in all cases.

Rather than add the original Downloads folder into iCloud, I've relied on the standard 'Documents and Desktop' sync option provided by Apple in iCloud without messing around in the background where those files are accessible (`~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/`) as I'm not confident that adding links in there is a good idea long term.

In terminal (or [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) if you want a more customisable terminal):

1. Create a 'Downloads' folder in your 'Documents' directory (if you haven't already): `mkdir ~/Documents/Downloads`
2. Copy (or move as with this example) your files from the old (presumed to be in `~/Downloads` directory to the new Downloads directory: `mv ~/Downloads ~/Documents/Downloads`
3. Delete your old Downloads folder (this should require your password, and presumes you are logged in as an administrator): `sudo rm -rf ~/Downloads/`
4. Create a symbolic link to your new Downloads folder: `ln -s ~/Documents/Downloads ~/Downloads`

All those commands again, but without all the extra words :)

```
mkdir ~/Documents/Downloads
mv ~/Downloads ~/Documents/Downloads
sudo rm -rf ~/Downloads/
ln -s ~/Documents/Downloads ~/Downloads
```

You will probably have to drag the new Downloads link (or folder) in Finder to the Favourites section/left menu if you want it to display there once more.

Comment: Are you simply deleting the original downloads folder so you are not redundantly storing data twice? If you did not delete the original ~/Downloads folder and you downloaded, say a pdf from chrome to ~/Downloads, would the data be stored in both the original downloads folder and the sym linked downloads folder? After you delete ~/Downloads would you have to edit your default path for downloads to the sym linked downloads folder, or is the original still there in the background somewhere and that’s how it knows to work?

Comment: @mturchin its a 'replace' rather than 'duplicate' - the OS thinks its the original folder in the original location (so no need to edit default paths for the downloads folder), but its now located in the iCloud via the Documents folder. The third command is the one deleting the old Downloads folder, and the fourth command is the one creating the presentation of the new folder in the original location, even though its not physically there...

Comment: This is a great answer. To add to it, there is a Service called [SymbolicLinker](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10433/symboliclinker) that will allow you to create symbolic links from the Finder. I don't know of a utility that will allow you to delete protected folders without using the Terminal, but surely there is one. Anyone heard of one?

Comment: Excellent. If anyone is admin for managed accounts (not sudo-ers) that you're doing this for (me, for my kids' Minecraft, etc. saved folders under ~/Library) you will need to (assuming "admin" is an account with admin privileges) change this slightly:
    mkdir ~/Documents/Downloads
    mv ~/Downloads ~/Documents/Downloads
    su admin
    sudo rm -rf ~/Downloads/
    sudo ln -s ~/Documents/Downloads ~/Downloads
With so much application data and states under ~/Library, am surprised that Apple hasn't included a mechanism to also sync user-specific Library items to iCloud as well.

Comment: should add a `chmod -h 700 ~/Downloads` to make the symlink's permissions equal to the old Downloads folder (fixes issues with system services, shortcuts, airdrop)

Comment: @JoshHibschman I am having trouble receiving AirDops using the setup from this answer. I tried running your suggested command in Terminal to fix it, but the AirDops still do not appear in the new symlinked Downloads folder. I am testing by AirDropping from my iPhone, and it says "Sent" on my iPhone, but the file never appears on my Mac (or at least I can't figure out where it's going). Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: @TinyTiger on the mac have the Finder Airdrop folder open so you can see each airdrop device

Comment: @JoshHibschman I can confirm that works, but previously that was not needed. Normally the file would be received without having the Finder AirDrop folder open. Is there any way to make it work like normal?

Answer (score 3):

You could create an 'Alias' of your 'Downloads' folder and move it to iCloud Drive.

To do this:

- Launch Finder and locate your 'Downloads' folder
- Right-click on your 'Downloads' folder and select 'Make Alias'
- Drag the new alias to 'iCloud Drive' in the Finder sidebar (You'll notice the animated pie graph icon filling up to the right of 'iCloud Drive' in the Finder window as it syncs)

You can now remove the word 'Alias' from the name of the folder in iCloud drive if you'd like. There is no real technical reason for it to be there other than to remind you that it's an alias and not the original folder.

Comment: This only uploads the alias file to iCloud Drive and not the contents of my Downloads folder. :/

Comment: @TreS I just tried my steps again in case I missed something and it's working perfectly for me. It's uploaded all contents of my Downloads folder including all sub-folders. I even went as far as to download a few new files to test and everything new that I download immediately syncs with the Downloads folder alias in iCloud Drive as well. What is the exact version of macOS Sierra that you are running?

Comment: I do confirm @TreS is correct. Only the alias but the contents is uploaded.

Comment: Same here. I think @NYKg has put the actual Downloads folder in iCloud and keep the Alias on his personal home folder.

Comment: Is creating this alias folder going to store the data twice though? Will the data be stored in both ~/Downloads and the new Downloads Alias Folder as well?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it on mine.

You have to understand that as of September 24, 2017, iCloud only allows `Desktop` and `Documents` folder to stored on iCloud. Eg. you cannot select yet additional folders you want to be synced to iCloud.

So, I chose to sync my `Downloads` folder by storing it in `Documents` folder because had I put it in iCloud-synced `Desktop` folder, the `Downloads` folder would be visible on my Desktop.

The `Downloads` folder is protected by macOS from changes (such as a rename on Finder), but if you can use the `Terminal` app to circumvent this.

1. Open Finder, and go to iCloud-synced `Documents` folder
2. Manually create a folder named `Downloads`
3. Move all your files in the original `Downloads` folder into this newly created `Downloads` folder located under `Documents` folder
4. Create a symbolic link for the newly-created `Downloads` folder (keyboard shortcut is: `Command` + `L`). It will be automatically be named `Downloads alias` by macOS
5. Put the newly-created `Download alias` under your home directory. Eg. `/Users/your-user-name`
6. Using the `Terminal` app, delete `Downloads` folder
7. Now, you can rename `Downloads alias` as `Downloads`

Now, all files saved through `Downloads` (alias) will be stored under iCloud-synced `Documents/Downloads` folder.

Comment: You are mixing up symbolic links and Apple's aliases. `Command` + `L` makes alias, not a symbolic link. However, your approach does works, whether using a regular UNIX symbolic link or an Apple alias.

Answer (score 1):

Using Aliases and Symbolic Links may not work.  On one of my Mac's, Finder replaced the symbolic link with an empty folder upon reboot.  The only way I've been able to consistently do this is to create a directory hard-link.  This is not possible with the default OS X command line as `ln` won't work if you're doing a hard-link to directories.

In order to do this, you need to install [Brew](https://brew.sh/) and install the [hardlink-osx package](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/hardlink-osx).  Though, before doing so one should consult [this question from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210741/why-are-hard-links-not-allowed-for-directories), as I think this function is disabled in all versions of the `ln` command.  Now, I had issues even with a hard link because the operating system did not notify the sync agent that a file in `~/Documents/Downloads` had been altered because the OS call to the file system was for `~/Downloads` and sometimes the sync finder extension did not seem to let the iCloud sync engine know there were changes to upload when a new file was downloaded or modified.

Answer (score -3):

preferences>icloud>options and check the box for "Desktop & Documents Folders"

Drag "Downloads" onto the desktop.

Done!

Comment: If you do this, macOS won't use the moved *Downloads* folder as its File Download Location.