# How to sync Downloads folder to iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization

I need to sync the Downloads folder to iCloud and then all the downloads should automatically sync with iCloud.

I tried to:

1. Create a new Downloads folder in the terminal of MacBook in the Documents directory.
2. Tried to move the default Download folder to the newly created folder.

When I tried to use the mv command to move the default Downloads folder to the newly created Downloads folder in Documents in the terminal, it gives permission denied error.

I am trying to achieve what was suggested by user PhillipHolmes in the below thread, please. Thank you:

[How to sync an additional folder to iCloud Drive similar to how macOS Sierra does it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270227/how-to-sync-an-additional-folder-to-icloud-drive-similar-to-how-macos-sierra-doe)

Thank you

Comment: All these answers give ways of doing this - but I would ask why do you want this. Downloads should be a temporary store before you process the file e.g. unzip it, use a dmg to install or read a document before filing

Answer (score 6):

#### Designate a new *Downloads* folder in the iCloud parent folder.

1. Create a new "Downloads" folder within iCloud. Either

   a.  In Finder → *iCloud Drive*, make a new folder called *Downloads*, or

   b.  In Terminal.app, run

   ```
   mkdir ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads
   ```
2. *Optional.* Move the contents of your old Downloads folder(s) to the new folder.
3. Delete your old Downloads folder on each computer
4. Make a softlink from your new iCloud folder to the traditional location on each computer. 
   In Terminal.app, run

   ```
   ln -s ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads ~/Downloads
   ```
5. Check that macOS knows about the new location on each computer. In Safari → Preferences → General, check that *File download location* is *~/Downloads*.

*Note: '~/' here denotes your User folder.*

Comment: @evert, I believe this is the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Anybody try this and get a permissions error on step 3?

Comment: You can get around this by deleting it from the terminal `sudo rm -rf ~/Downloads` just make sure you have all the files out of there first.

Comment: It seems to me `~/Documents` and `~/Desktop` are *not* symlinks when they sync to iCloud. I'm actually not sure what's the behind the scenes setup Apple uses. But can `~/Downloads` be configured in the same way as ~/Documents and ~/Desktop?

Comment: I would love for it to work that way, but I don't know enough about how Apple has implemented  `~/Documents` and `~/Desktop` to mimic them.

Comment: Seems that this will break AirDrop?

Answer (score 5):

#### Move and Softlink

1. Turn on iCloud Sync for *Documents & Desktop Folders*.

[image: Navigating Preferences]

2. Move your old *Downloads* folder to iCloud

   ```
    sudo mv ~/Downloads ~/Documents/Downloads
   ```
3. Link the new and old locations

   ```
    ln -s ~/Documents/Downloads ~/Downloads
   ```
4. *Optional.* Drag the *~/Downloads* link to the sidebar in Finder.

Comment: This method also retains the keyboard shortcuts for navigating to the downloads folder, in case that is important to your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Set your Download location as Desktop or Documents in Safari Preferences → General

Then turn on iCloud for Documents and Desktop in System Preferences → iCloud → iCloud Drive Options.

You might need to move existing content  in your new download location somewhere else.

For your later edit, just set the Download location in Safari Preferences → General as `Documents/downloads_folder_you_made` and the turn on the sync. You might need to move the existing content in the default Downloads folder to the newly made one.

Comment: Thank you ankii I needed help with was was suggsted in this thread.https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270227/how-to-sync-an-additional-folder-to-icloud-drive-similar-to-how-macos-sierra-doe

Comment: @NoWorriesEducation  you might need to update the question then :)

Comment: User PhillipHolmes suggested to create a new folder and move the content to the new folder in the terminal and they make the computer think that its' downloading in the default Downloads folder. Thank you But I need help with permission denied error .

Answer (score 0):

#### Designate a new *Downloads* folder in iCloud Documents

This method doesn't require use of the command line interface, so it's easier for novice and intermediate users.

1. Turn on iCloud Sync for *Documents & Desktop Folders*.

[image: Navigating Preferences]

2. Pick a new "Downloads" folder within iCloud:

   a.  *Documents*,

   b.  *Desktop*,

   c.  Create *Documents → Downloads*, or

   d.  Create *Desktop → Downloads*.
3. In Safari → Preferences → General, set *File download location* to the new folder.
4. *Optional.* Move the contents of your old *~/Downloads* folder(s) to the new folder.
5. *Optional.* Delete your old *~/Downloads* folder(s)

Comment: What I don't understand is, why is everyone recommending to create a downloads folder in the iCloud's Documents or Desktop folder? I don't know about you guys, but I just have a Downloads folder in the root of my iCloud. And I don't even remember manually creating it. I think it was automatically created when I downloaded something with Safari in iOS. So why not copying your files over and then delete the folder on your Mac and replacing it with a symbolic link?

Comment: That's a good question. I remember trying what you suggest and deciding to take a different route, but I don't remember why. These are my best guesses: (a) Perhaps there was a time when the iOS Files app wouldn't show a iCloud/Downloads folder, but it does now. (b) The path for iCloud/Downloads is very ugly: ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads, versus  the much cleaner /Users/merc/Documents/Downloads for this method. Of course, that can be addressed with a softlink.

Comment: Third possibility: (c) @keba was skeptical of the wisdom of creating links within the parent iCloud folder in this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/311513/2622

Comment: It's completely fine to create folders in the root folder. These are stored in the com~apple~CloudDocs folder as mentioned. If you don't want this, then you have to pick Desktop or Documents.