# How to get keyboard shortcut for downloads folder work again after deleting downloads folder?

Tags: macos, finder, shortcut

I tried to get my downloads folder synced with iCloud and followed this tutorial: [How to sync an additional folder to iCloud Drive similar to how macOS Sierra does it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270227/how-to-sync-an-additional-folder-to-icloud-drive-similar-to-how-macos-sierra-doe?newreg=9197fe50c58a4044a9aadea22b3ee24a)

However, I did not like the result, so I tried to reverse its effects and "reinstalled" the downloads folder in my user folder by simply creating a new folder and naming it "Downloads". Everything seems to work (Safari files get downloaded into this folder, this folder is accessible via the dock etc.)

My problem: The keyboard shortcut (<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) is not directing me to the downloads folder whenever I am in finder. All other keyboard shortcuts in finder still work.

Do you have any tips or suggestions on how to get the shortcut to work again? I rely heavily on keyboard shortcuts in finder, so this problem is very annoying.

Thank you.

Btw: I am using macOS 10.15.2, if that is of any relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is the default key but if it is not working, I would suggest you create a new service in Automator.

1. Set the dropdowns to Service receives to no input, in any application, or limit it to just the Finder if you like.
2. Add the "**Run Shell Script**" item, and set the content to open `~/Downloads`
3. Save the Service, name it whatever you like.
4. In the keyboard shortcuts preference pane, select "**Services**" from the source list.

Find the service you created at the bottom of the list on the right, and give it whatever shortcut you'd like. I hope this will help you.

Comment: That did help. Thank you for putting in the effort, your solution works! :-)

Comment: Great to know. Would you be kind to accept my answer too :) ?